# How to redirect to dropbox and get back to my application with access token(how to login with dropbox)

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, dropbox

I have created an app in Dropbox and followed this steps to get the files and folder of my Dropbox Account:
https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/dotnet#tutorial

But I want to get files and folders of any user with my app.
Means user can click on "*Button*" and redirect to Dropbox login page after successful login he will be redirect to my application page which is set in dropbox app and can see the files and folders.

When user click on button this code executes:

```
public ActionReault LoginWithDB()
{
  DropNetClient _client = new DropNetClient("MyAppKey", "MyAppSecret");
  string redirecturl = "https://localhost:44361/";
  **string url = _client.GetTokenAndBuildUrl(redirecturl);**
  var accessToken = _client.GetAccessToken();
}
```

Getting this error:

> "Received Response [BadRequest] : Expected to see [OK]. The HTTP
>   response was [{"error": "v1_retired"}]." at marked line

Simply if I can get the access token of user after successful login I can work following these steps:
https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/dotnet#tutorial

Please help me how to redirect to dropbox account and redirect back to my application page with access token.

Comment: "v1_retired" sounds to me as if you are using an API function that is not supported any more. See https://www.dropbox.com/developers/reference/migration-guide

Comment: From that link: _"In June 2016, we announced the deprecation timeline for API v1. When API v1 is retired in September 2017, any further **API v1 calls will fail with a 400 error with the body: {"error": "v1_retired"}**"_

Answer (score 1):

The `v1_retired` error does indicate that you're making a Dropbox API v1 call. Dropbox API v1 is now retired, so those API calls will fail.

You linked to [the Dropbox.NET tutorial](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/dotnet#tutorial), which is for [the official Dropbox API v2 .NET SDK](https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox-sdk-dotnet). That is the recommended way for accessing Dropbox API v2.

Your code, however, instead uses `DropNetClient`, which is from the unrelated and unofficial [`DropNet`](https://github.com/DropNet/DropNet) library. ([The note there for `DropNet`](https://github.com/DropNet/DropNet#note-development-of-dropnet-has-stopped) does indicate that it does not use API v2.)

You should instead install the official `Dropbox.API` library as [documented here](https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox-sdk-dotnet#setup).

You should refer to [the SimpleBlogDemo sample app](https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox-sdk-dotnet/tree/master/dropbox-sdk-dotnet/Examples/SimpleBlogDemo) for an example of sending an arbitrary user through the Dropbox OAuth app authorization flow. For instance, [here is the code where the authorization URL is generated and the user is redirected to it](https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox-sdk-dotnet/blob/master/dropbox-sdk-dotnet/Examples/SimpleBlogDemo/Controllers/HomeController.cs#L176).